# How to remove the delay when changing colors for Scaffold and TopBar (Material 3)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

When I change the value of the **containerColor** variable, the color first changes for the entire Scaffold and only then the color of the topBar changes. There is a noticeable delay of approximately 300 milliseconds.

```
var containerColor by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.White) }

Scaffold(
    containerColor = containerColor,
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                containerColor = containerColor
            )
        )
    }
)
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes of container color of `TopAppBar` are animated down in `SingleRowTopAppBar` [here](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/95ef295b9867e91bd2e4f1265b4d2a13eb772dc9:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/AppBar.kt;l=1653):

```kotlin
val appBarContainerColor by animateColorAsState(
    targetValue = colors.containerColor(fraction),
    animationSpec = spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow)
)
```

You can make compose not to reuse the same "instance" of `TopAppBar` but rather create a new one when the color changes, which will do the change immediately, like this:

```kotlin
var containerColor by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.White) }

Scaffold(
    containerColor = containerColor,
    topBar = {
        key(containerColor) {
            TopAppBar(
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = containerColor
                )
            )
        }
    }
)
```